# Tag [tf] mistakenly used for tensorflow questions and redundant with [tfs] tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request, tag-disambiguation

I recently noticed questions related to Tensorflow (the deep learning framework) mistakenly tagged with the [tf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tf) tag that stands for the Team Foundation Server.

Digging a bit more I found that the Team Foundation Server has its own tag [tfs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tfs) with a bit less than 20k questions. The [tf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tf) tag counts 167 questions, 28 of which are actually Tensorflow questions.

It seems that with the growth of Tensorflow, a good move would be to make the [tf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tf) tag disappear as too confusing with the TensorFlow abbreviation TF and redundant with the mostly used [tfs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tfs) tag.

Comment: Worth mentioning that [tag:tensorflow] is the official tag that some of these questions should be moved to. Note also that [tag:tf] is *not* synonymous with [tag:tfs] -- the latter is Team Foundation Server, the former is a command-line tool used with the server (as explained in the tag info). Might want to consider renaming that tag to somethine like [tag:tf-cli]

Comment: I started to remove the tag [tag:tf] for some questions about Tensorflow (questions for which both tags were present)

Comment: Title suggestion, "What [tf] is this tag about?"

Comment: @BhargavRao that's so genius that it's evil.

Comment: Why do we even have abbreviation tags? Are 'team-foundation-server' and 'tensorflow' somehow insufficient?

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas So we should also have [tag:hypertext-markup-language] and [tag:php-hypertext-processor] instead of [tag:html] and [tag:php]?

Comment: @TylerH No, we literally have [tensorflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tensorflow). We also have [team-foundation-server] but it's apparently a synonym for tfs. Also since tensorflow is one word, 'tf' would be a weird abbreviation; 't' would be the abbreviation.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas I'm not sure what your argument is. The point of this question is that people are using [tag:tf] to mean [tag:tensorflow] *and that it's a bad thing*, ***because*** [tag:tf] ***is for the team foundation CLI***. So... it sounds like you're just agreeing with the OP, but in an oddly argumentative tone.

Comment: TF doesn't mean *anything*. tf.exe, sure. It can join xsd.exe, sendmail.exe, and the rest of the executable family that have dedicated tags. As an ambiguous abbreviation it should be, at best, a redirect.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas hence OP's suggestion to get rid of [tag:tf]. So, again... what's your argument?

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas, _Why do we even have abbreviation tags?_, because some one created the abbreviation tag once, without looking at whether the expanded version exists or not. The reason why people are using tf for tensorflow is that, the usual tensorflow import in python is `import tensorflow as tf`, just like how it is `import numpy as np` for numpy.

Answer (score 5):

I agree a moderator or CM should rename [tf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tf) to [tf-cli](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tf-cli). I *think* the remaining ~117 or so questions are all about the tf.exe command-line tool. They're certainly all about TFS or TF version-control, at least.

There were a number of misuses for [tf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tf). I've gone through the tag and retagged many of the questions (about 41 or so) with a more appropriate tag (along with editing the questions and/or VTCing where appropriate).

- [tensorflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tensorflow) - TensorFlow questions
- [tf-idf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tf-idf) - questions on text frequency or importance in a document/doc collection
- [transfer-function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/transfer-function) - MATLAB questions

And a few other scenarios where there isn't an applicable tag (people using the [tf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tf) tag for an abbreviated version of an iOS app called TestFlight, for example).